# Traer los datos relacionados a una fecha usando localdate o string en un query jpa

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy trabajando con JPA en spring boot junto a sql server, debo. Debo hacer un `@query` que me permita buscar aquellos datos relacionados a una fecha.

La cuestión es que estoy intentando parsear un string a localDate para realizar la consultarconsulta:

```
String neow = "2022-09-12"
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse(neow);
List<Venta> diaVenta = repositorioVentas.getComprasPorDia(fecha);
```

La cuestión es que no sé si en el query estoy formulándolo bien ya que el programa lanza error. El error empieza así:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:143) ~[na:na]
```

Es¿Es mejor recibir como parámetro un string o el mismo localdate, o me falta hacer algún casteo a nivel del query para que esteesté correctamente formulado?

```
 @Query("SELECT c FROM Venta c where DIA_COMPRA=:Dia")
 List<Venta> getComprasPorDia(@Param("Dia") LocalDate dia);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola!

No es necesario que definas la query encima ya que JPA trae incorporado el `findBy`

En cuanto a si usar `String` o `Date`, si en la bbdd el campo fecha es un Varchar, usa un string, si por el contrario es tipo date usa el tipo de dato Date

Con algo así te valdría:

```
List<Venta> findByFecha(Date fecha);
```

Ojo que donde pone Fecha tendras que poner el nombre del campo en tu bbdd, es decir, si tu guardas el dia de la compra en el campo 'miFechaCompra'
el metodo deberá llamarse:

```
List<Venta> findBymiFechaCompra(Date fecha);
```

Te dejo un poco de info ampliada:

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-search

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977018/jpa-how-to-get-entity-based-on-field-value-other-than-id